# Is it possible to replace user input data before post in browser level via javascript (or JQuery) on Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Just take Google search as example, I don't want to "hack" google search.

I am wondering is it possible to write some userscript (javescript) base on browser (firefox/Chrome,etc) addon (eg: Tampermonkey) , and --

when user input "123" ,and hit "enter" or click "search" button .

Then the script will intercept and check on my API (or say database) , "123" is map to "456", then it send "456" as search keyword to google server.

Then finally, on browser Google return back the search result of "456"

( "123" can be treat as other language text , "456" can be treat as the English translate of "123" , so Google search will always return back the English version result )

Is it possible in technically? 
Any simple demo user javascript ?

Thanks !

Comment: Basically, you need to add an event listener for "submit" event and use its `target` property to access the form and its elements so that you can endure them and change. There should be many examples you can use as a starting point.

Comment: You say "check on my API / DB". Is the API / DB on the internet or inline the script?